# Export and Import single column in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table name `products` in my database which has a column name `gallery`. I just want to export the table `gallery` locally and import it into live.

I have successfully exported the table `gallery` but now I am not able to import it in PHPMyAdmin.

Is it possible to import only one column?

Comment: If you want to use PHPMyAdmin the PHP tag is unrelated. The UI doesn't use PHP code for execution. You likely won't be able to achieve this with that tool. You could use PHP and import that single column, if you want to do that you should show what you've tried and add the PHP tag back.

Comment: You might be able to generate the UPDATE SQL in your SELECT. e.g. SELECT 'UPDATE products SET gallery = ', gallery, ' WHERE id = ', id, ';'; or some such thing. Then you do ALTER TABLE on live to create the gallery column and run the UPDATEs.

Comment: I don't think you can import just one column into a table. Import usually indicates creating new rows in a table and this is the feature that is supported by phpmyadmin and other GUI mysql clients. In your case, however, you would need to update a column. But you have only one column in your dataset, so there is no way to tell which gallery value belongs to which row in the prod table. Even if you had additional column(s) that let you determine which row the gallery value is associated with, you cannot import the data via phpmyadmin into that table in one go.

Comment: You would have to import the dataset into a temporary table on prod, then using a multi-table update statement bring the gallery values into their proper table.